# Melhor cardinalidade para uma tabela com muitas relações

Tags: mysql, modelagem

Bom, eu tenho uma tabela de **fluxo de caixa**, esta tabela pode estar relacionada a um processo, pedido, conta a receber, conta a pagar... dentre várias outras tabelas que se relacionam e que podem resultar em um lançamento no caixa, o problema é na hora de criar as relações nesta tabela, não sei se crio várias foreign keys, uma para cada tabela (em fluxo de caixa), ou uma tabela de relacionamento (HAS) que são as alternativas que conheço, creio eu que seria um problema para manutenção do banco uma destas duas, já que no sistema os módulos são dinâmicos e a qualquer momento pode haver um novo, e que precise lançar no fluxo de caixa e ter este lançamento rastreado (relacionado).

Minha ideia seria uma única tabela de relacionamento que serviria para todos os relacionamentos, e que estaria ligada a outra que indicaria qual seria a tabela de relacionamento, Ex:

**Tabela de relacionamento:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `SIS_REL` (
  `PK_rel` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `FK_rel_parent` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'a',
  `FK_rel_child` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'b',
  `FK_table_parent` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'c',
  `FK_table_child` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'd',
  PRIMARY KEY (`PK_rel`)
);
```

**Tabela que define qual será o relacionamento:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `SIS_rel_group` (
  `PK_rel_group` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `rel_table` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`PK_rel_group`)
);
```

Mas não sei se daria certo e se seria viável vendo pelo lado dos padrões de modelagem de dados e desempenho, vejo que alguns sistemas como o **SAP** tudo se relaciona com tudo (ou quase), mas não faço ideia de como eles fazem no banco, mas com certeza devem ter encontrado uma boa solução, agradeço desde já.

Comment: Que tal criar em cada tabela (processo, pedido, conta a receber, conta a pagar) um relacionamento para fluxo de caixa em vez do inverso?

Comment: Funcionaria, mas não sei se é a melhor saída.

Comment: Você relatou os problemas das suas duas opções e eu posso adicionar alguns - primeira opção: vários campos nulos no fluxo de caixa por não fazerem sentido para todas as entidades; segunda opção: uma complexidade acidental na modelagem de dados, que afastaria as tabelas da modelagem de negócio (uma tabela de relacionamento genérico dificilmente descreveria bem o negócio). Qual seria o problema da opção que eu sugeri?

Comment: Eu concordo com o Caffé, relações genéricas vão te dar dor de cabeça no futuro, principalmente quando voce precisar indexar essas relações.

Answer (score 2):

Existe um solução que foi encontrada por alguns frameworks mas não tenho certeza se poderá ser a solução para o seu problema.

A idéia é fazer com que a tabela que terá relação com várias outras tabelas na verdade tenha uma relação genérica, ou seja, uma relação que permite que qualquer outra tabela seja vinculada a ela.

Para fazer isso funcionar é necessário que você tenha dois campos, um que recebe o nome da tabela relacionada e outro que recebe o valor da chave primária que está sendo relacionada.

Exemplo:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `fluxo` (
  `PK_fluxo` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `rel_table` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `rel_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`PK_fluxo`)
);
```

A partir daí sempre que você quiser relacionar uma linha de uma tabela qualquer à tabela de fluxo você tem que inserir o nome da tabela a chave primária dela.

Imagine que você quer relacionar a linha 127 da tabela `contas_a_pagar` a um fluxo, você tem que executar a seguinte query:

```
INSERT INTO fluxo (rel_table, rel_id) VALUES ('contas_a_pagar', 127);
```

Como sempre, existem prós e contras. E o principal contra é o SELECT que não pode ser feito de forma fácil usando JOIN. Para fazer o SELECT é necessário fazê-lo em duas etapas.

O primeira SELECT:

```
SELECT * FROM fluxo;
```

Aí é necessário iterar sobre as linhas e guardar todas as tabelas e IDs. Depois você constrói um SELECT para pegar as relações:

```
SELECT * FROM contas_a_pagar WHERE PK_contas_a_pagar = 127;
```

E na aplicação você tem que juntar os resultados usando a chave primária de `contas_a_pagar`.

O Django usa [esse tipo de abordagem](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations) para resolver o problema de Relação Genérica.

Espero que tenha ajudado, ou pelo menos servidor de inspiração para você resolver o seu problema.

Comment: Estou fazendo alguns testes com essa solução, parece ser uma boa ideia, estamos procurando falhas que possam acontecer no futuro usando este modelo, breve darei um feedback.